# Speed up Convolution Function C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, filtering, convolution

I am trying to implement an "adaptive" convolution for image filtering that limits the maximum or minimum possible values of the output pixel by predetermined bounds. I haven't found any functions in opencv that will allow me to do this, so I wrote my own that accomplishes what I am looking for. (Is there perhaps a different library?) The only issue is that this function takes about 0.9 seconds,whereas the time it takes cv::filter2D to filter an image is about 0.005 seconds (both with the same kernel). Does anyone know how I can speed up my method?

A couple of comments about my kernel: it is a 9x9 custom sharpening filter, and the kernel IS NOT separable. I tried redesigning my filter to be separable, but I cannot achieve the desired results. Any thoughts? Below is the function I use for my code:

```
Mat& adaptive_convolution(Mat& img)
{

    fstream in("kernel.txt");
    string line;

    float v[9][9];
    int i = 0, k = 0;

    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        float value;
        int k = 0;
        stringstream ss(line);

        while (ss >> value)
        {
            v[i][k] = value;
            ++k;
        }
        ++i;
    }


    clock_t init, end;
    double minVal;
    double maxVal;
    Point minLoc;
    Point maxLoc;

    int pad_fact = 4;
    int top, left, bottom, right;

    Mat new_image = img;
    top = pad_fact; bottom = pad_fact;
    left = pad_fact; right = pad_fact;

    copyMakeBorder(img, new_image, top, bottom, left, right, BORDER_CONSTANT, 0);

    minMaxLoc(img, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
    new_image / 2^8;
    init = clock();
    double temp = 0;

    for (int i = pad_fact; i < img.rows + pad_fact; i++)
    {
        for (int j = pad_fact; j < img.cols + pad_fact; j++)
        {
            for (int ii = -pad_fact; ii <= pad_fact; ii++)
            {
                for (int jj = -pad_fact; jj <= pad_fact; jj++)
                {
                    //temp = double(v[ii + 2*pad_fact][jj + 2*pad_fact]); 
                    temp = temp + double(v[ii + pad_fact][jj + pad_fact] * float(new_image.at<uchar>(i - jj, j - ii)));
                    //temp = double(new_image.at<uchar>(i - jj, j - ii));
                }
            }
            if (temp > maxVal)
            {
                temp = maxVal;
            }
            else
            {
                if (temp < minVal)
                {
                    temp = minVal;
                }
            }
            new_image.at<uchar>(i, j) = temp;
            temp = 0;
        }
    }



    img = new_image;
    end = clock();
    cout << float(end - init)/1000 << endl;
    return img;
}
```

EDIT:

I was able to speed up the convolution in a python script I am using to about 0.2 seconds using Numba. I still need to see this kind of improvement using c++. Am I being help back by using opencv?

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.autojit
def custom_convolve(image,kernel,pad_fact):
    pad_fact = int(pad_fact)
    filt_im = np.zeros(image.shape)
    rows = image.shape[0]
    columns = image.shape[1]
    glob_max = np.max(image)
    glob_min = np.min(image)

    for x in range(pad_fact,columns-pad_fact,1):
        for y in range(pad_fact,rows-pad_fact,1):
            pix_sum = 0
            for k in range(-pad_fact,pad_fact,1):
                for j in range(-pad_fact,pad_fact,1):
                    pix_sum = pix_sum + kernel[k+pad_fact,j+pad_fact]*image[y-j,x-k]

            if pix_sum > glob_max:
                pix_sum = glob_max
            elif pix_sum < glob_min:
                pix_sum = glob_min

            filt_im[y,x] = pix_sum
    return filt_im
```

Comment: Is is possible to parallelize computing `new_image.at<uchar>(i, j)`?

Comment: Does using a "parallel_for_" for the outermost loop make sense? I am not exactly sure how to write the arguments in the parallel_for_ loop from the reading. I am also seeing that there are many different ways to parallel the loop using particular c++ libraries. Do you recommend any method in particular?

Comment: Why can you not clamp the values *after* the convolution?

Comment: Clamping the values after convolution causes wrapping in the image and doesn't save me much computation time. OpenCV filter2D must handle this a different way, but I am having trouble figuring that out.

Comment: I think parallel_for for the outermost loop should make sense. Just make sure to get thread-local and shared data correct (assuming you're talking about OpenMP)

Comment: I found this for parallel loop: `#pragma omp parallel for`. Specifying `private(...) shared(...) num_threads(...)` does change computation time by much.. am I missing something?

Comment: It may be too small of a problem to parrallelize at that scale. There is overhead to it.

Comment: What does your build environment look like? Are you sure you are building with optimizations? If you want to use openmp are you sure you are building with openmp enabled (just adding the pragmas isn't enough you have to tell the compiler you are building with openmp).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the basic OpenCV implementations are using [SSE function](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#) which allows two process additon etc. parallel by using 128 bit variable. Another trick is if the filter kernel is [separable](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/) and can be composed as follows:

K = D * D'

where * denotes the convolutation operator and D is a vector e.g. [1 2 1], and K the final kernel. Than you can substitute the filtering of an image A to the image B:

B = A * K;

with

B = A * D (*) (A' * D)'

here (*) denotes the pixelwise multiplication, A' denotes the transposed image i.e ' the transpose sign.

Comment: From my original post, my kernel is not separable. I will take a look at the SSE function.